# Target framework while publishing

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a publish profile for an ASP.NET CORE application. While building it I only have the option for netcoreapp2.0. Other developers have netcoreapp2.1. I just updated my Visual Studio 2017 to 15.8.0 but I still do not have this option. What do I need to install or upgrade on my computer to allow that target framework to be available while building a publish profile?

Comment: Do you have a global.json in your project folder or in one of the folders above your project? Have you installed the correct version (x86, x64)? whats the output of  `dotnet --info` and probably most important: does your project target `netcoreapp2.1` in the first place?

Comment: No global.json in my project. The server that I am publshing to certainly has 2.1. In part the of dotnet --info i do see: .NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
...

Comment: Everything @Tseng said, but my money is on you're missing the SDK. Visual Studio updates don't include .NET Core SDK updates. You have to install those separately. https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Comment: @SeanW.: Your machine has to have the correct SDK, the server's runtime version doesn't matter from a publishing standpoint (though it will obviously fail to run after be deployed if the version isn't correct).

Comment: Not just in you project but in any parent folders of it. If your Project is in `C:\Projects\.NET Core\2.1\MyProject` the the global.json could be in 2.1, ".NET Core", "Projects" or "C:\" folders. But most interesting is `Version:   2.1.400` line

Comment: Thanks ya so my projects go in to C:\Users\Me\source\repos\. From C:\Users\Me\ i did dir global.json /s /p and I didn't get any results. So ya i am really not sure why I cannot select netcoreapp2.1. And actually I just created a new project and it's available in the new project but not my existing project. What will become of my existing project? Can I just not use it? Do I need to start over from a new project and hope that copying and pasting code will work?

Comment: You can edit your csproj and change the value for `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp2.1` there.